# HttpClient doesn't returned all response headers

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I agree this is a duplicate question but i have tried answers given in other posts and that doesn't work so i am posting mine with my code

I have a situation in which i'm making a GET call with custom header and the response also contains a custom header. Response obtained using HttpClient contains only 4 headers but not custom header sent from my server. I can see the custom header in Network tab of chome's dev tool. Below is the code I am using

```
doGetFullResponse(path: string, headerExtra: any) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let authData = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if(authData) {
      headers = headers.append('Authorization', "BEARER "+authData);
      if(headerExtra) {
        for(let key in headerExtra) 
          headers[key] = headerExtra[key];
      }
      //httpClient is HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'
      return this.httpClient.get(path, {headers: headers, observe: "response"});
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
    }
  }
```

i am calling this function as

```
this.httpservice.doGetFullResponse().subscribe((res)=>{
      //this.pointAudits = res.json();
      res.headers.keys().map((key)=>console.log(key+":"+res.headers.get(key)));
    })
```

below is the output:

> pragma:no-cache content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate expires:0

the custom header sent from my server "`MAX_ITEM_COUNT`" doesn't appear here. Is there anything that i am missing? I am using angular 4.
Let me know if any detail is needed.

Comment: you sure of setting `MAX_ITEM_COUNT` from server properly. share your server code .

Comment: Its pretty simple code. response.addHeader('my-header', 'my value'). My header is coming in respnse i can see that in dev tool of chrome

Comment: ah you able to see in chrome ! then you might need to check on `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` which might come handy. you can expose you're custom header by setting to it,basically some headers are meant to be interpreted by a browser which are not exposed while accessing .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : Reply HttpHeaders from HttpResponse are stripped. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457599/angular-2-reply-httpheaders-from-httpresponse-are-stripped-how-to-fix)

Comment: Server should give explicit permissions for the client to read specific custom headers (via the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header)